# How to delete rows from same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that logs requests and responses. The table has a **timestamp** column and a transaction type column with 2 possible values: **req**, **resp**. Regardless of the why, I have **resp** rows that have no matching **req** row.

I am trying to delete all **resp** rows that don't have a matching **req** row with the same timestamp. Any ideas?

What i need in pseudocode is:

Delete all rows in *table* where transaction type equals **resp** and has no matching **req** row with the same timestamp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Delete Table t
Where TxType = 'resp'
  And Not Exists
   (Select * From Table
    Where timestamp = t.timestamp
       and TxType = 'req')
```

(Inside of a transaction so you can roll it back if it fails!)

and oh yeah,  Chris Lively from below raises an excellent point.. When you refer to a "***TimeStamp***" are you speaking generically? or are you talking about the SQL Server Timestamp data type that is guaranteed to be unique ?? If the former, and you are actually using a datetime or some such, then Are you sure you can't have two or more different requests at the exact same time ??

Comment: I am talking generically, it is actually a datetime. And the datetime fields do match. There is actually another field on the table that shows the datetime of each transaction, but this one is really the datetime that the request came in for matching requests and responses.

Comment: @Jarmon, then you need to be careful that more than one request does not come in at the exact same time..  perhaps this has not happened as yet, but with this design it could...

Answer (score 1):

something like the following ought to do it.

```
delete mytable
  from mytable t1
     left outer join mytable t2 
         and (t2.TimeStamp = t1.TimeStamp)
         and (t2.TransactionType = 'req')
  where (t2.TimeStamp is null)
    and (t1.TransactionType = 'resp')
```

After looking at this, is the tie inbetween the two records really a timestamp?  It just seems to me that the timestamps would be different and instead you have some other key that links the two together.

Comment: yes the timestamps are the same for matching purposes. There is actually another timestamp that is actual time of each transaction. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you

```
delete T1
from @T as T1
where
  T1.[Type] = 'resp' and
  T1.[TimeStamp] not in (select [TimeStamp]
                         from @T as T2
                         where T2.[Type] = 'req')
```

And some test code

```
declare @T table ([TimeStamp] datetime, [Type] varchar(5))

insert into @T values
('2001-01-01', 'req'),
('2001-01-01', 'resp'),
('2002-01-01', 'resp'),
('2003-01-01', 'req')

print 'Before delete'
select *
from @T

delete T1
from @T as T1
where
  T1.[Type] = 'resp' and
  T1.[TimeStamp] not in (select [TimeStamp]
                         from @T as T2
                         where T2.[Type] = 'req')

print 'After delete'
select *
from @T
```

Output

```
(4 row(s) affected)
Before delete
TimeStamp               Type
----------------------- -----
2001-01-01 00:00:00.000 req
2001-01-01 00:00:00.000 resp
2002-01-01 00:00:00.000 resp
2003-01-01 00:00:00.000 req

(4 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

After delete
TimeStamp               Type
----------------------- -----
2001-01-01 00:00:00.000 req
2001-01-01 00:00:00.000 resp
2003-01-01 00:00:00.000 req

(3 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH T AS
(
SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [TimeStamp] ORDER BY [Type]) RN
FROM YourTable
)
DELETE FROM T 
WHERE Type='resp' AND RN=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM YourTable
WHERE Timestamp IN (
  SELECT Timestamp FROM YourTable WHERE TransactionType = 'resp'
  EXCEPT
  SELECT Timestamp FROM YourTable WHERE TransactionType = 'req'
)
```